# Mac won't open sites after installing avast

Tags: firewall

Sorry if it's wrong place to ask a question like this. I installed Avast to fix a malware, and then all websites barring few (basically Google) won't open. I've uninstalled avast but the problem persists.

I've checked Firewall, reset permissions using Onyx but the issue persists.

I can open all sites in safe mode. And I've removed all files of Avast. Still the problem persists. My login items doesn't list any other program.

Please help. I have the latest mac OS installed.

Comment: This belongs on the think different site, I've flagged it to be moved. They'll want more details, like what happens when you try and open a site

Comment: Which site is it?

Comment: Sorry I meant ask different and it's at http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RobM Chances are SuperUser will be a better spot for this. It's not really Apple-specific.

Comment: My first guess would be that the malware did something to your internet settings to allow it to inject ads, capture your logins, etc; and that Avast deleted the malware but didn't fully clean up the damage it had done. It'd help a lot to know exactly what the malware was.